# HTML таблица

Tags: html

Создал в HTML таблицу как управлять фоном и текстом всей таблицы понятно, каждой отдельной ячейки понятно, а как управлять фоном и текстом ряда или колонки не прописывая каждую ячейку?

Answer (score 1):

Аналогично . Те же атрибуты только для тега <tr> . А с колонками проблема - есть тег <col>, но он слабо поддерживается браузерами.
Вообще такие вещи нужно делать на CSS. . Вот, кстати, [пример](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_col.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Вот ещё примерчик http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.html

HTML

```
<table>
<col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col>
<tr><th>Month<th>1994<th>1995<th>1996...
```

CSS

```
col:first-child {background: #FF0}
col:nth-child(2n+3) {background: #CCC}
```